# Can I get the video texture cycling without freezing? Eevee

Tags: texturing, materials, eevee-render-engine, image

I am using video files and image sequences to make some interesting textures onto object, I set up the frames number, checked Auto Refresh and Cycle. But before repeating it freezes for like 10-20 frames and then starts over again. Is it some sort of render limitation? I am mostly working in Eevee

Comment: Does it freeze only in viewport or also in final render?

Comment: You can help the users who would help you. Please show images of your current node setup, and the render settings.